# Opacity animation doesn't work after thread sleep (c# wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm creating a back button (named BackGrid) that's supposed to appear whenever I put my cursor inside a grid and disappear after .7 seconds if the cursor still isn't inside the grid or back button.

The appearing part works well but the disappearing part doesn't seem to work.

I did some minor troubleshooting and tried the following:

1. Removed the whole Task.Factory code and placed `animateBackViewBox(false);` right below the `CursorInsideSubGrid = false` just to try and see if the animation runs fine independently. The result was that it runs correctly.
2. My concern shifted to the Task.Factory code since it was the first time I've used it and was worried that I've implemented it incorrectly so I commented out `animateBackViewBox(false);` and entered `MessageBox.Show("You left after .7 seconds");` instead. The result was that it runs correctly as well.

So currently I'm stumped on where the actual problem lies since both of them work fine independently.

```
    private void ItemSubGrid_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        CursorInsideSubGrid = true;
        animateBackViewBox(true);
    }

    private void ItemSubGrid_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        CursorInsideSubGrid = false;

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(700);
            if(CursorInsideSubGrid == false)
            {
                animateBackViewBox(false);
            }
        });
    }

    void animateBackViewBox(bool show)
    {
        DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();

        if (show == true)
        {
            BackGrid.IsHitTestVisible = true;
            da.From = BackGrid.Opacity;
            da.To = 100;
        }
        else
        {
            BackGrid.IsHitTestVisible = false;
            da.From = BackGrid.Opacity;
            da.To = 0;
        }

        da.AccelerationRatio = 1;
        da.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300));
        BackGrid.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty,da);
    }
```

Comment: I used a Dispatch Timer instead and it did the trick (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063433/dispatchertimer-tick-once).

Answer (score -1):

Some time ago I also had trouble with the GUI and the updating. In my case, I had a Progress-Bar named Loading with a label on it, the Problem was, that the label was a "hole" in the GUI
I could solve it by

```
Loading.Update();
```

I don't know if it's Fitting for you but worth a try

Link to my mentioned question/answer: [c# Label is "empty"/is a hole in the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38479693/c-sharp-label-is-empty-is-a-hole-in-the-form)

Comment: What namespace does Loading use on WPF? Intellisense can't seem to recommend one.

Comment: Please read my description properly; I have a PROGRESSBAR named LOADING which I call with UPDATE (the WPF equivalent is `.UpdateLayout`). I copied your code and it worked for me, please don't downvote just because you don't understand

Comment: Except I didn't downvote you, I was actually preoccupied with reading the link you gave as I found it useful. Just to prove it, I'll downvote you and retract it after 30 minutes.

Comment: Well it didn't even let me downvote since I lack the reputation to, so that should be enough proof.

Comment: My bad then, there are too many give-me-the-answer-directly guys ^^

Comment: No worries, as someone who still has a lot to learn, I'm very thankful for any new information I could get.